# Problemas com captcha e variavel email

Tags: php

```
<?php     
  if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $senha = $_POST['senha'];
  $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];

  if($nome == ''){
  echo 'Qual é o seu nome?';
  }elseif(strlen($nome)<3){
   echo'Insira um nome existente';
  }elseif($sobrenome==''){
 echo 'Qual é o seu sobrenome';
  }elseif(strlen($sobrenome)<4){
    echo'Insira um sobrenome existente';
  }elseif($email==''){
  echo 'Insira seu email';
  }elseif(!preg_match("/^[az0-9_\.\-]+@[az0-9_\.\-}*{a-z0-9_\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i",$email)){   
   echo 'E-mail invalido tente outro';
  }elseif($senha==''){
  echo 'Você precisa ter uma senha';

    }else{

        include('../../sllapsocial/classes/DB.class.php');

        $verificar = DB::getConn()->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `usuarios` WHERE `email`=?");
        if($verificar->execute(array($email))){
            if($verificar->rowCount()>=0){
         echo 'Este e-mail ja existe';

     }elseif($senha=='' OR strlen($senha)<4){
        echo'Senha fraca Insira mais caracteres';
     }elseif(strtolower($captcha) <> strtolower($_SESSION["captchaCadastro"])){
         echo 'Codigo errado';
     }else{
         $Senha = sha1($senha);
         $nascimento = "$ano-$mes-$dia";
         $Inserir = DB::getConn()->prepare("INSERT INTO `usuarios` SET `email`=?, `senha`=?, `nome`=?, `sobrenome`=?, `sexo`=?, `nascimento`=?, `cadastro`=NOW()");

         if($Inserir->execute(array($email,$senha,$nome,$sobrenome,$sexo,$nascimento))){
        header('Location: ./');  
           }

        }

       }

    }

    }


  ?>
```

Comment: Pessoal sei que voces estao cansado de ver esse meu formulario mais nunca achei o problema É o seguinte o nome e sobrenome cadastra normal o campo email aparece a seguinte mensagem  'Email invalido tente outro' ai eu tento outro e isso ocorre progressivamente ,e o captcha nunca funciona

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dei uma refatorada no seu código, fazendo uma lógica mais linear para ao menos ver se você consegue visualizar melhor onde está tendo problemas.

De qualquer forma, você não anda prestando atenção em todas as recomendações e continua misturando maiúsculas e minúsculas, esquecendo `;` no final das linhas, e uma série de outros probleminhas. Já melhorou com os `$_POST`, mas é melhor arrumar tudo que puder de uma vez só antes de postar nova pergunta, senão vamos ter milhares delas e você quase não vai avançar.

```
<?php
   require_once( '../../sllapsocial/classes/DB.class.php' );

   if( @$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
      $nome =      $_POST['nome'];
      $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
      $email =     $_POST['email'];
      $senha =     $_POST['senha'];
      $sexo =      $_POST['sexo'];
      $ano =       $_POST['ano'];
      $mes =       $_POST['mes'];
      $dia =       $_POST['dia'];
      $captcha =   $_POST['captcha'];

      $erro = '';

      if( $nome == '' ) {
         $erro .= 'Qual é o seu nome?<br>';
      } elseif ( strlen( $nome ) < 2 ) {
         $erro .= 'Insira um nome existente<br>';
      }

      if( $sobrenome == '' ) {
         $erro .= 'Qual é o seu sobrenome<br>';
      } elseif( strlen( $sobrenome ) < 2 ) {
         $erro .='Insira um sobrenome existente<br>';
      }

      if( $email == '' ) {
         $erro .= 'Insira seu email';
      } elseif( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
         $erro .= 'E-mail invalido tente outro<br>';
      }

      if( $senha == ''  OR strlen( $senha ) < 4 ) {
         $erro .= 'Você precisa ter uma senha<br>';
      }

      $verificar = DB::getConn()->prepare( 'SELECT `id` FROM `usuarios` WHERE `email`=?' );
      if( $verificar->execute( array( $email ) ) ) {
         if( $verificar->rowCount() > 0 ){
            $erro .= 'Este e-mail ja existe<br>';
         // } else {
            // Se quiser, tire os comments deste código para testar se chegou aqui
            // $erro .= 'Email livre. Pode remover esse else do código<br>';
         }
      } else {
         $erro .= 'Erro interno ao verificar o e-mail<br>';
      }

      if( strtolower( $captcha ) <> strtolower( $_SESSION["captchaCadastro"] ) ) {
         $erro .= 'Codigo errado<br>';
      }

      if( $erro === '' ) {
         $senha = sha1($senha);
         $nascimento = "$ano-$mes-$dia";
         $inserir = DB::getConn()->prepare( 'INSERT INTO `usuarios` SET `email`=?, `senha`=?, `nome`=?, `sobrenome`=?, `sexo`=?, `nascimento`=?, `cadastro`=NOW()' );
         if( $inserir->execute( array( $email, $senha, $nome, $sobrenome, $sexo, $nascimento ) ) ) {
            {
               header('Location: /');
            }
         }
      }
      die( $erro );
   }
?>
```

O código continua com outros problemas, como vulnerabilidade a SQL Injection, mas está mais linear. Daria pra melhorar bastante, mas na atual situação é bom que ele fique mais fácil de entender do que otimizado.

Mudei o jeito que suas mensagens de erro da aplicação aparecem, elas vão acumulando na variável `$erro` e são mostradadas ao final, assim você primeiro resolve os problemas de sintaxe, e depois os de lógica.

Outra coisa, do jeito que você restringe o tamanho do nome e do sobrenome, vai ter um monte de chineses bravos que não vão poder usar seu sistema. E a validação de email eu substitui por um `filter_var`, mas o ideal mesmo é checar só se tem uma arroba e um ponto do lado direito dela, para não eliminar emails válidos.

Comment: Acho que dificilmente chineses usarão esse sistema :D

Comment: @Bacco Muito obrigado eu estava dormindo mal por causa desse formulario '-'

Comment: @LamborghiniAventador dei uma editada pra resolver a questão que você postou recentemente, aquele "else" era pra ser um debug, e no fim esqueci de por uma explicação no código. o >= estava errado, e eu copiei do original sem perceber.

Comment: Muito bom @Bacco tudo esta ok , enfim o formulário não apresenta nenhum erro  :)