# Como verificar existência de email?

Tags: php

Estou inserindo usuários em banco de dados e ao clicar em "submit" no formulário diz para inserir o e-mail e este e-mail já existe.

Andei analisando mudei `[rowCount()>=0]` para `[rowCount()>=1]` ,deu

> Erro interno 1 ao verificar o e-mail

Ou seja, nunca valida o e-mail , fico agradecido!

```
require_once( '../../site/classes/DB.class.php' );

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
  $email =     $_POST['email'];
  $erro = '';


 $verificar = DB::getConn()->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `usuarios` WHERE `email`=?");

  if( $verificar->execute( array( $email) ) ) {
     if( $verificar->rowCount()>=0){
        $erro .= 'Este e-mail ja existe<br>';
     } else {
        $erro .= 'Erro interno 1 ao verificar o e-mail<br>';
     }
  } else {
     $erro .= 'Erro interno 2 ao verificar o e-mail<br>';
  }
```

?>

Comment: **Erro interno 1 ao verificar o e-mail** isso não existe, ou o email está cadastrado ou não - essa condição não indica erro pois é um comportamento **esperado**. O que você quer fazer é, validar um email, ou verificar se existe?

Comment: editado-verificar a existencia @PapaCharlie

Comment: Entenda: `rowCount()>=0` quer dizer que se a consulta for zero ou maior que zero, vai exibir **Este e-mail ja existe**. Uma consulta para um email que não existe vai retornar `rowCount 0`. Logo `0>=0`, ou `1>=0`... sempre vão exibir a mensagem acima.

Comment: entendi bem a lógica @PapaCharlie Mais qual é a solução obvia?

Comment: Pelo visto não entendeu, mas sua resposta esta [**aqui**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12433498/1244639). De mão beijada, basta copiar o código. Estou deixando o link pois seu código esta mais errado que imagina.

Comment: Meu rei, valeu estou meio parado com php, estou aprendendo jquery. por isso fiz essa pergunta meio que óbvia.

Comment: Não há problema. Tentei fazer você perceber a lógica, para não ter erros futuros.

Comment: Muito bom, voltarei a estudar php,afinal é uma das linguagem mais importantes para a programação, até mais

Comment: @PapaCharlie na verdade isso aí era pra ser um debug do código na questão anterior pra ver se estávamos chegando até aí, mas no fim esqueci de detalhar isso na questão relevante. Agora eu pus um comment na outra resposta pra ficar mais evidente.

Comment: @PapaCharlie vai sair dai uma resposta?

Comment: @Bacco, de uma questão antiga não é? Acho que lembro, esse exemplo está rolando a um tempão :)

Comment: @JorgeB., não pensei em dar uma resposta em definitivo, encerrei no link que recomendei. Se quiser pode dissertar sobre ela. Essa query pode trocar por um `count` e um fetch. Eu passo a bola.

Comment: Acho melhor fechar essa depois de resolver, pq o problema estava na anterior (senão vai ficar mais uma desse tipo pendurada no site) @LamborghiniAventador veja a questão original, que arrumei lá.

Comment: Corrigi o ">", que eu copiei do código original e nem reparei, e pus um comment descritivo no lugar do "else". Tinha reescrito o código todo, e acabei distraindo nesse pedaço. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34161/70